# TypeError: method() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a code:

```
class Child(object):
    def chunks(l, n):
        """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
        """
        for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
            yield l[i:i+n]

k= range(1, 10)
print k
print Child().chunks(k,2)
```

When I execute this code, python throws following error:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>    "/home/Sample.py", line 19, in
>
> print Child().chunks(k,2)
>
> TypeError: chunks() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Please find my snippet !

Comment: `def chunks(self, l, n):`

Comment: @Kay TypeError: chunks() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) , I need a explanation

Comment: `self` is passed automatically, so you are actually passing `(self, k, 2)` (3 arguments) to the `chunks` method, but it is defined to accept `(l, n)` (2 arguments), hence the error. Edit in Kay's answer and see for yourself!

Comment: @Matthew  Thanks. Let me try...

Comment: There is clearly *no need* for `chunks` to be in `Child`; just make it a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instance method**: A method that is defined inside a class and belongs only to the current instance of a class.

Define `chunks` method as instance method in class.

e.d

```
class Child(object):
    def chunks(self, l, n):
        #      ^^^   
        pass
        # do coding
```

**[Static Method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)**:

```
class Child(object):
    @staticmethod
    def chunks(l, n):
        pass
        # do coding
```